# node js module exports for firebase initialization function

Tags: node.js, firebase, module, firebase-admin

I was trying to use firebase-admin in my node js project. below is code of my main page:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const  ejs = require('ejs');
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const app = express();

// const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(
//     functions.config().firebase
// );
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/getPosts', require('./routes/posts'));
app.use('/tests', require('./routes/tests'));
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
exports.firebaseApp = function(){
    return firebase.initializeApp(
        functions.config().firebase
    );
}
```

The code of the file - **./routes/tests** is given below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
//
// const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(
//     functions.config().firebase
// );
const firebaseApp = require('../index.js').firebaseApp;
function getPosts(){
    const ref = firebaseApp.database().ref('users');
    return ref.once('value').then(snap => snap.val());
}

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    getPosts().then(posts => {
        res.json(posts);
    });


});
module.exports = router;
```

The problem is, when I visit `http://localhost:5000/getPosts`, it says **TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined**. What is the preoblem here?
Adding

```
firebase.initializeApp(
        functions.config().firebase
    );
```

in every layout page, is not a good idea because it'll initialize firebase multiple times.
How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: I'm very surprised that you have a file that requires another file, which in turn requires the first file.  That seems like poor design.  Consider having a single file that they both require, in order to get a hold of the things they have in common.

Comment: K. I'll try it out!

Comment: This way of initializing the app has been removed. Refer [Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions Migration Guide: Beta to version 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#functionsconfigfirebase_removed). firebase.initializeApp( functions.config().firebase ); The app must now be initialized with firebase.initializeApp();
Hope it helps.

Comment: That is working but if I add the code `const firebaseApp = require('./connect.js').firebaseApp();
function getPosts(){
    const ref = firebaseApp.database().ref('users');
    return ref.once('value').then(snap => snap.val());
}

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    getPosts().then(posts => {
        res.json(posts);
    });


});` in multiple files, that returns an error.

Comment: The firebase.initializeApp is used on multiple pages for multiple uses.

Comment: If you have a different issue than the one in the question, please create another question and explain the new problem there.

Comment: Answering [https://stackoverflow.com/q/51121533/10016659] alsocsolves this question.